# Can I parameterize AWS lambda functions differently for staging and release resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function invoked by S3 put events, which in turn needs to process the objects and write to a database on RDS. I want to test things out in my staging stack, which means I have a separate bucket, different database endpoint on RDS, and separate IAM roles.

I know how to configure the lambda function's event source and IAM stuff manually (in the Console), and I've read about lambda aliases and versions, but I don't see any support for providing operational parameters (like the name of the destination database) on a per-alias basis. So when I make a change to the function, right now it looks like I need a separate copy of the function for staging and production, and I would have to keep them in sync manually. All of the logic in the code would be the same, and while I get the source bucket and key as a parameter to the function when it's invoked, I don't currently have a way to pass in the destination stuff.

For the destination DB information, I could have a switch statement in the function body that checks the originating S3 bucket and makes a decision, but I hate making every function have to keep that mapping internally. That wouldn't work for the DB credentials or IAM policies, though.

I suppose I could automate all or most of this with the SDK. Has anyone set something like this up for a continuous integration-style deployment with Lambda, or is there a simpler way to do it that I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround using [Lambda function aliases](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html). Given the [`context` object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html#python-context-object-props), I can get the `invoked_function_arn` property, which has the alias (if any) at the end.

```
    arn_string = context.invoked_function_arn       
    alias = arn_string.split(':')[-1]
```

Then I just use the alias as an index into a dict in my config.py module, and I'm good to go.

```
config[alias].host
config[alias].database
```

One thing I'm not crazy about is that I have to invoke my function from an alias every time, and now I can't use aliases for any other purpose without affecting this scheme. It would be nice to have explicit support for user parameters in the context object.

Comment: We are doing this too! Did you also find a solution for having separate IAM roles per alias? It seems pretty dangerous to share roles between test and production..

Comment: Unfortunately no I didn't. I really didn't even like having the bucket names and database URLs in the same module either. The root problem is that Lambda requires the same role for all aliases.